# Disable checkbox click via CSS

Tags: html, css, checkbox

Is it possible to disable `checkbox` clicks via `CSS`. But keeping the functionality of the `checkbox` intact So we can set its values dynamically using `Javascript`. I wasn't able to find a proper solution.

```
pointer-events:none
```

did not work

Comment: Only disable clicking on the checkbox. But the checkbox values can still be set dynamically

Comment: You can do that with HTML - `<input type="checkbox" disabled >`.

Comment: then whats the `functionality` of check box????

Comment: use disabled="disabled" html property

Comment: I think it states: is this posible via CSS

Comment: +10 NoobEditor .. good question ..

Comment: In my case it is only used to display something.

Comment: @Jacob : then what **Vucko** said should be your answer..... :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `pointer-events` is not supported in your browser, then no, not with css only.

Comment: The problem is that `pointer-events:none` only works for inputs where the value is changed as a result of the "pointer event". Inputs like checkboxes and radio buttons change their state, not their value, when interacted with. Doesn't make your answer incorrect, but there's a hair to split in that `pointer-events` *can* be supported and this still won't work.

Comment: remember that despite disabled pointer events you still can 'tab' to the checkbox and toggle it using the 'space' key!

Comment: @KeithS A valid point. Even worse, this (and all of the other CSS 'hacks', like putting a glass panel in front or setting `visibility: none`) breaks down, as soon as you have a label for your checkbox, because interacting with that is the same as interacting with the checkbox.

Answer (score 33):

just the `html` solution will be like this.

```
<input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" id="checkBox"/>
```

if you wish to do this using `javascript`

```
document.getElementById("checkBox").disabled=true;
```

Comment: Green Wizard not sure how your first solution is just **css**?? Setting the disabled attribute on the element is an HTML solution.

Comment: Oh no worries Green Wizard! +1 for the JS solution :)

Answer (score 16):

You can put a transparent div on top of the checkbox to make it un-clickable by toggling a class on the parent object.
Something like this...

```css
.container{
  position:relative;
  display:block;

}
.cover{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:transparent;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:2;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  display:none;

}

.container.disable-checkbox .cover{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="cover"></div>
  <input type="checkbox"/> "clickable"

</div>
<div class="container disable-checkbox">
  <div class="cover"></div>
  <input type="checkbox"/> "un-clickable"
</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

You probably need some javascript for this. You could use this exemple if you're running jQuery:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
})
```

Or a quick and dirty method, add an onClick attribute to the checkbox like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" onClick="return false;">
```

Comment: This still sets the css styles for the checkboxes so it looks like it was clicked.

Comment: I needed to prevent it from uncheked. Just added checked attribute on your solution and it worked. +1 for this.

Answer (score 8):

This is possible by setting `pointer-events: none` on a parent element of the checkbox :)

Answer (score 3):

I have covered 2 methods here: https://animatedcreativity.com/blog/2020/09/14/css-disable-checbox/

You can reduce the checkbox opacity to make it look disabled or use a pseudo-element for cover.

```css
input[type="checkbox"]:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0.5;
  pointer-events: none;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:nth-child(3) {
  position: relative;
  pointer-events: none;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:nth-child(3):before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
<!-- using opacity -->
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
<!-- using layer -->
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
```

Comment: "pointer-events: none;" was the answer. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could do this via jQuery:

```
$('.element-view'.attr('disabled', true);
```

Comment: This is not using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

with JQuery:

```js
$("input[type='checkbox']").attr("disabled","disabled")
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    disabling checkboxes
  </head>
  <body>
      <form>
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
        <input type="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox">
      </form>
  </body>
</html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is not using CSS.

Answer (score -1):

No, it doesn't seem possible.

You may need to HIDE IT. Use *input type="hidden"* to store information and process it using JS.